# State machine compression

Tags: compression, graph-theory, mathematical-optimization, state-machine

I have a log of outputs given the inputs, for example:

```
0 =A=> 1 =B=> 1 =B=> 0 =A=> 1 =A=> 0 =A=> 0
```

And I would like to find the minimal state machine representing it.

I tried, by hand, to break it down into an ordered list of transitions:

1. `0 =A=> 1`
2. `1 =B=> 1`
3. `1 =B=> 0`
4. `0 =A=> 1`
5. `1 =A=> 0`
6. `0 =A=> 0`

If we considered that there are only two states:

- `q0` with output `0`.
- `q1` with output `1`.

The list becomes:

1. `q0 (0) =A=> q1 (1)`
2. `q1 (1) =B=> q1 (1)`
3. `q1 (1) =B=> q0 (0)`
4. `q0 (0) =A=> q1 (1)`
5. `q1 (1) =A=> q0 (0)`
6. `q0 (0) =A=> q0 (0)`

We can see that from the state `q0`, the input `A` leads to q1 in lines 1 & 4, but to state `q0` in line 6.
Same issue in the `q1` state with the action `B`. 
So I have to create two additional states `q2` with output `0`, and `q3` with output `1`. 
I can then rewrite the list the following way:

1. `q0 (0) =A=> q1 (1)`
2. `q1 (1) =B=> q3 (1)`
3. `q3 (1) =B=> q0 (0)`
4. `q0 (0) =A=> q1 (1)`
5. `q1 (1) =A=> q2 (0)`
6. `q2 (0) =A=> q0 (0)`

And done.

It seems simple by hand but I can't find an algorithm to achieve that given list of transitions.
I know that there are several solutions to this example, but I need that can find one.

I considered to treat this as an optimization problem and use for instance a simulated annealing or a genetic algorithm, but this seems overkill.
Plus, I really feel that there is a simple way to do that, maybe something related to graphs theory?

**Edit:**

Thanks to @sascha's comment, now I know that the following list describes a nondeterministic finite state automaton (NDFA):

1. `q0 (0) =A=> q1 (1)`
2. `q1 (1) =B=> q1 (1)`
3. `q1 (1) =B=> q0 (0)`
4. `q0 (0) =A=> q1 (1)`
5. `q1 (1) =A=> q0 (0)`
6. `q0 (0) =A=> q0 (0)`

There are algorithms out there to convert it a deterministic finite state automaton (DFA), see [NDFA to DFA conversion](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/ndfa_to_dfa_conversion.htm)

I will try that tomorrow, however, I am worried that I won't get minimal DFA equivalent to this NDFA.

Comment: This looks like a nondeterministic finite state automaton, where minimization is hard. Maybe you got additional structure to be assumed leading to some polynomial minimization though.

Comment: @sascha I don't know the structure, sorry. So maybe, I should give a try to a metaheuristic?

Comment: @sascha So I've looked it up and I need to have deterministic finite state automaton, i.e., going from a state given an input always leads to the same state..

Comment: What language do you plan on writing this in, VHDL?

Comment: @Rob Python 2, I cannot use another language. But I want to get the algorithm right first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to do what I want (which works on this example at least):

A. From the output log `0 =A=> 1 =B=> 1 =B=> 0 =A=> 1 =A=> 0 =A=> 0` I build a transition list:

1. `q0 (0) =A=> q1 (1)`
2. `q1 (1) =B=> q2 (1)`
3. `q2 (1) =B=> q3 (0)`
4. `q3 (0) =A=> q4 (1)`
5. `q4 (1) =A=> q5 (0)`
6. `q5 (0) =A=> q6 (0)`

B. I convert it into a state table:

```
 q  │ A  │ B  │ Output
────┼────┼────┼────────   
 q0 │ q1 │ ── │ 0     
────┼────┼────┼────────   
 q1 │ ── │ q2 │ 1     
────┼────┼────┼────────   
 q2 │ ── │ q3 │ 1     
────┼────┼────┼────────   
 q3 │ q4 │ ── │ 0     
────┼────┼────┼────────   
 q4 │ q5 │ ── │ 1     
────┼────┼────┼──────── 
 q5 │ q6 │ ── │ 0     
────┼────┼────┼────────   
 q6 │ ── │ ── │ 0
```

C. I then use the [Moore Reduction Procedure](https://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Johnson/ECE152A/L12%20-%20Machine%20Minimization.pdf). Since the machine is incompletely specified, choices have to be made.

`P0 = [{q0, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6}]`

`P1` is the list of states grouped by output: `P1 = [{q0, q3, q5, q6}, {q1, q2, q4}]`

`P1[0]` is `{q0, q3, q5, q6}`:

- `q0(A) = q1 ∈ P1[1]`
- `q0(B) = ?`
- `q3(A) = q4 ∈ P1[1]`
- `q3(B) = ?`
- `q5(A) = q6 ∈ P1[0]`
- `q5(B) = ?`
- `q6(A) = ?`
- `q6(B) = ?`

So `q0` and `q3` are compatible with each other, `q5` is not compatible with them. `q6` can be compatible with any of these states, here we will choose to group `q6` with `q0` and `q3`.

`P1[1]` is `{q1, q2, q4}`:

- `q1(A) = ?`
- `q1(B) = q2 ∈ P1[1]`
- `q2(A) = ?`
- `q2(B) = q3 ∈ P1[0]`
- `q4(A) = q5 ∈ P1[0]`
- `q4(B) = ?`

So `q1` and `q2` are NOT compatible with each other. `q4` can be compatible with any of these states, here we will choose to group `q4` with `q1`.

So we have `P2 = [{q0, q3, q6}, {q5}, {q1, q4}, {q2}]`

`P2[0]` is `{q0, q3, q6}`:

- `q0(A) = q1 ∈ P2[2]`
- `q0(B) = ?`
- `q3(A) = q4 ∈ P2[2]`
- `q3(B) = ?`
- `q6(A) = ?`
- `q6(B) = ?`

So `q0`, `q3`, and `q6` are still compatible with each other.

`P2[1]` is `{q5}`: `q5` is compatible with itself.

`P2[2]` is `{q1, q4}`:

- `q1(A) = ?`
- `q1(B) = q2 ∈ P2[3]`
- `q4(A) = q5 ∈ P2[1]`
- `q4(B) = ?`

So `q1` and `q4` are still compatible with each other.

`P2[3]` is `{q2}`: `q2` is compatible with itself.

So we have `P3 = [{q0, q3, q6}, {q5}, {q1, q4}, {q2}] = P2`.

We now have the following state table

```
  q            │ A            │ B            │ Output
 ──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼────────   
  {q0, q3, q6} │ {q1, q4}     │ ──────────── │ 0     
 ──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼────────   
  {q1, q4}     │ q5           │ q2           │ 1     
 ──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼────────   
  q2           │ ──────────── │ {q0, q3, q6} │ 1     
 ──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼────────   
  q5           │ {q0, q3, q6} │ ──────────── │ 0
```

And... voilà!

Thanks for the comments, they really helped me to make the right queries on search engines.

Edit: Since choices have to be made, it is reasonable to assume that this approach is generally sub-optimal. To make it optimal, I guess that the only way is to try all the combinations of choices and choose the best one.

Comment: The implementation I made works as expected, so I guess this method works. I don't think I will share my implementation since this is only an algorithm-to-code conversion.